# How to setRequestContent in SoapUI with OnRequest Mock Script (groovy)

Tags: groovy, soapui

My problem is:
I get Soap-requests in UTF-8-BOM at my SoapUI Mock. SoapUI cannot handle UTF-8-BOM. If I try to handle UTF-8-BOM request I get an error "org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Content is not allowed in prolog."
I wanna replace the first byte in the request using OnRequest Script.

I wrote this code in "OnRequest Script" to replace the first byte of my request.

```
def mockRequestContent
try {
    mockRequestContent = mockRequest.getRequestContent()
    mockRequestContent = replace(mockRequestContent) // method returns substring(1)
    mockRequest.setRequestContent(mockRequestContent)
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.info(e)
}
```

But when I send a response to my Mock, I don't get errors at the tab "script log", but I get an error at the tab "error log" (see below).

What is the right way to set request content?

Error on the tab "error log"

```
 Mon Mar 06 19:02:26 MSK 2017:ERROR:org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script25.groovy: 97: unexpected token: catch @ line 97, column 4.
    } catch {Exception e} {
      ^
org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: unexpected token: catch @ line 97, column 4.
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:140)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:236)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:162)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:912)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:574)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:550)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:527)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:279)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:258)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:613)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:625)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:652)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:643)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.compile(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:136)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:87)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.dispatch.ScriptMockOperationDispatcher.selectMockResponse(ScriptMockOperationDispatcher.java:87)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockOperation.dispatchRequest(WsdlMockOperation.java:199)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockDispatcher.dispatchPostRequest(WsdlMockDispatcher.java:219)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockDispatcher.dispatchRequest(WsdlMockDispatcher.java:114)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockRunner.dispatchRequest(WsdlMockRunner.java:142)
    at com.eviware.soapui.monitor.JettyMockEngine$ServerHandler.handle(JettyMockEngine.java:604)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:945)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: Script25.groovy:97:4: unexpected token: catch
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.tryBlock(GroovyRecognizer.java:9344)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.statement(GroovyRecognizer.java:1130)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.blockBody(GroovyRecognizer.java:1495)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.openBlock(GroovyRecognizer.java:8315)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.variableDefinitions(GroovyRecognizer.java:2364)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.declaration(GroovyRecognizer.java:2140)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.statement(GroovyRecognizer.java:1208)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.compilationUnit(GroovyRecognizer.java:757)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:131)
    ... 33 more

1 error

   org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
   Script25.groovy: 97: unexpected token: catch @ line 97, column 4.
        } catch {Exception e} {
         ^
   org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: unexpected token: catch @ line 97, column 4.
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:140)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:236)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:162)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:912)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:574)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:550)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:527)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:279)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:258)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:613)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:625)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:652)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:643)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.compile(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:136)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:87)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.dispatch.ScriptMockOperationDispatcher.selectMockResponse(ScriptMockOperationDispatcher.java:87)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockOperation.dispatchRequest(WsdlMockOperation.java:199)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockDispatcher.dispatchPostRequest(WsdlMockDispatcher.java:219)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockDispatcher.dispatchRequest(WsdlMockDispatcher.java:114)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockRunner.dispatchRequest(WsdlMockRunner.java:142)
    at com.eviware.soapui.monitor.JettyMockEngine$ServerHandler.handle(JettyMockEngine.java:604)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:945)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
   Caused by: Script25.groovy:97:4: unexpected token: catch
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.tryBlock(GroovyRecognizer.java:9344)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.statement(GroovyRecognizer.java:1130)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.blockBody(GroovyRecognizer.java:1495)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.openBlock(GroovyRecognizer.java:8315)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.variableDefinitions(GroovyRecognizer.java:2364)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.declaration(GroovyRecognizer.java:2140)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.statement(GroovyRecognizer.java:1208)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.compilationUnit(GroovyRecognizer.java:757)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:131)
    ... 33 more
   1 error
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:309)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addFatalError(ErrorCollector.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:119)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:131)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.addError(SourceUnit.java:359)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:142)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:236)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:162)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:912)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:574)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:550)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:527)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:279)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:258)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:613)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:625)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:652)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:643)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.compile(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:136)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:87)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.dispatch.ScriptMockOperationDispatcher.selectMockResponse(ScriptMockOperationDispatcher.java:87)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockOperation.dispatchRequest(WsdlMockOperation.java:199)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockDispatcher.dispatchPostRequest(WsdlMockDispatcher.java:219)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockDispatcher.dispatchRequest(WsdlMockDispatcher.java:114)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockRunner.dispatchRequest(WsdlMockRunner.java:142)
    at com.eviware.soapui.monitor.JettyMockEngine$ServerHandler.handle(JettyMockEngine.java:604)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:945)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Mon Mar 06 19:02:26 MSK 2017:ERROR:com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.DispatchException: Failed to dispatch using script; org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script25.groovy: 97: unexpected token: catch @ line 97, column 4.
    } catch {Exception e} {
      ^
org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: unexpected token: catch @ line 97, column 4.
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:140)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:236)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:162)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:912)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:574)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:550)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:527)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:279)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:258)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:613)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:625)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:652)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:643)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.compile(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:136)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:87)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.dispatch.ScriptMockOperationDispatcher.selectMockResponse(ScriptMockOperationDispatcher.java:87)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockOperation.dispatchRequest(WsdlMockOperation.java:199)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockDispatcher.dispatchPostRequest(WsdlMockDispatcher.java:219)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockDispatcher.dispatchRequest(WsdlMockDispatcher.java:114)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockRunner.dispatchRequest(WsdlMockRunner.java:142)
    at com.eviware.soapui.monitor.JettyMockEngine$ServerHandler.handle(JettyMockEngine.java:604)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:945)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: Script25.groovy:97:4: unexpected token: catch
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.tryBlock(GroovyRecognizer.java:9344)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.statement(GroovyRecognizer.java:1130)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.blockBody(GroovyRecognizer.java:1495)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.openBlock(GroovyRecognizer.java:8315)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.variableDefinitions(GroovyRecognizer.java:2364)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.declaration(GroovyRecognizer.java:2140)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.statement(GroovyRecognizer.java:1208)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.compilationUnit(GroovyRecognizer.java:757)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:131)
    ... 33 more

1 error

   com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.DispatchException: Failed to dispatch using script; org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
   Script25.groovy: 97: unexpected token: catch @ line 97, column 4.
        } catch {Exception e} {
         ^
   org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: unexpected token: catch @ line 97, column 4.
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:140)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:236)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:162)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:912)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:574)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:550)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:527)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:279)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:258)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:613)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:625)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:652)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:643)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.compile(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:136)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:87)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.dispatch.ScriptMockOperationDispatcher.selectMockResponse(ScriptMockOperationDispatcher.java:87)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockOperation.dispatchRequest(WsdlMockOperation.java:199)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockDispatcher.dispatchPostRequest(WsdlMockDispatcher.java:219)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockDispatcher.dispatchRequest(WsdlMockDispatcher.java:114)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockRunner.dispatchRequest(WsdlMockRunner.java:142)
    at com.eviware.soapui.monitor.JettyMockEngine$ServerHandler.handle(JettyMockEngine.java:604)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:945)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
   Caused by: Script25.groovy:97:4: unexpected token: catch
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.tryBlock(GroovyRecognizer.java:9344)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.statement(GroovyRecognizer.java:1130)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.blockBody(GroovyRecognizer.java:1495)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.openBlock(GroovyRecognizer.java:8315)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.variableDefinitions(GroovyRecognizer.java:2364)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.declaration(GroovyRecognizer.java:2140)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.statement(GroovyRecognizer.java:1208)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.compilationUnit(GroovyRecognizer.java:757)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:131)
    ... 33 more
   1 error
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.dispatch.ScriptMockOperationDispatcher.selectMockResponse(ScriptMockOperationDispatcher.java:91)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockOperation.dispatchRequest(WsdlMockOperation.java:199)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockDispatcher.dispatchPostRequest(WsdlMockDispatcher.java:219)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockDispatcher.dispatchRequest(WsdlMockDispatcher.java:114)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockRunner.dispatchRequest(WsdlMockRunner.java:142)
    at com.eviware.soapui.monitor.JettyMockEngine$ServerHandler.handle(JettyMockEngine.java:604)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:945)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Why do you have curly brackets around `Exception e` in the stacktrace - `} catch {Exception e} {` but `(Exception e)` in the code?

Comment: @EelLee It's not my error. It looks like, that "} catch {Exception e} {" is native Soap UI code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I use your code as a `OnRequest script` on the MockService (adding a `log.info` to trace the request at first):

```
def mockRequestContent
try {
    mockRequestContent = mockRequest.getRequestContent()
    // log request
    log.info mockRequestContent
    mockRequestContent = mockRequestContent.substring(1)
    mockRequest.setRequestContent(mockRequestContent)
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.info(e)
}
```

And as a `Dispach: SCRIPT` for mock operation I log again the response which is `substring(1)` due to previous `OnRequest script`:

```
log.info  mockRequest.getRequestContent()
return 'DefaultMockResponseName'
```

If I start the Mock service and send this as a sample XML (the first `<` is for the sample to remove the first character):

```
<<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <Header/>
   <Body>
      <test> 
      </test>
   </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Then in the `Script log` I see the expected output where the first character was removed:

```
Tue Mar 07 11:36:22 CET 2017:INFO:<<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><Header/><Body><test></test></Body></Envelope>
Tue Mar 07 11:36:22 CET 2017:INFO:<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><Header/><Body><test></test></Body></Envelope>
```

If it can help I'm trying with *SOAPUI version 5.2.1*

Comment: Thx a lot. I just need someone who can say that this code works well. Problem was in my script that I call at mock response.